# Seeing the satellite images of the Antarctica and its research stations

Tags: ground-station

I found a very nice expedition to Antarctica later in Dec and Jan which I plan to onboard. Meanwhile, I would like to see all available satellite photos of all research stations down there, including Amundsen Scott.

Where could I find this please?

Thank you.

Comment: If you do a Google Earth search for "Antarctic Base" you will get 39 hits with links to Wikipedia articles.

Answer (score 3):

I happen to have Google Earth Pro open at the moment. I typed 'Antarctic Base' into the search box, and got a list of four:

- Princess Elizabeth
- Halley Research
- Commandante Ferraz
- Almirante Brown

Selecting any of them will bring up zoomable satellite pictures. (Google Earth Pro is free.)